# DataTables child rows not displaying properly when filled using PHP ECHOs

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatables

I have looked at all the examples I can find but haven't found an answer to this.

I have a DataTables table which is loaded by PHP echos, after manipulating data from MySQL queries.

I now want to add child rows showing extra data, basically the same format type as the DataTables examples (http://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html)

I have modified the table by adding an extra `<tr>`, and have added the details-control class  (Simplified code below)

```
<tbody>
  <?php 
    while($fetch = $query->fetch_array()) {
      /*
      processing to build 15 variables used as data in main row <td>s
      and 8 variables used in the "hidden" rows
      */
      echo '<tr id = "parent">';
        echo '<td class="details-control"></td>';  /* taken from the DT example */
        echo '<td>'.$MainVariable.'</td>'; 
        /* repeated for all 15 of the main row variables */
      echo '</tr>';
      /* Now this should be the child row */
      echo '<tr id="child">';   
        echo '<td colspan="5">';
           echo 'Text: <b>'.$ChildVariable.'</b><br />';
           /* repeated for 6 of the child row variables */
        echo '</td>';

        echo '<td colspan="5">';
           echo 'Text: <b>'.$ChildVariable.'</b><br />';
           /* repeated for remaining 2 of the child row variables */
        echo '</td>';

        echo '<td colspan="5">';
           /* reserved for possibly more data */
        echo '</td>';
     echo '</tr>'; 
          }  
  ?>
</tbody>
```

The Javascript I have tried is below

```
$(document).ready(function() {

// Add event listener for opening and closing details
  $('#attendtbl').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
      var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
      var row = table.row(tr);

      if (row.child.isShown()) {
          // This row is already open - close it
          row.child.hide();
          tr.removeClass('shown');
      } else {
          // Open this row
          row.child(format(tr.data('child-value'))).show();
          tr.addClass('shown');
      }
  });
});
```

This shows all the data correctly, but all the child are shown displayed when the table loads, and the on('click' doesn't work.

Looking at all the DataTables examples I can find all the data seems to be loaded by Javascript/AJAX. which is something I don't really want to do.

I assume there must be a Javasript fault, but this is a new area for me.

Comment: One immediate problem is that you seem to be creating multiple `<tr>` elements with the same id (`child`). This is invalid - ids must be unique. If you need to label them so that you can address them all together, you might want to  use a class instead.

Comment: I have modified the ids using a PHP variable $i and incrementing it during the loop ( echo '<tr class="child" id="hidden '.$y.'">'; )

Comment: Hmm, just a thought, but maybe you could json_encode your query data instead of building the table and then you'd be able to do it more like the example from the documentation. You don't have to load it with AJAX. You can just output the encoded data in the page with PHP.

Comment: I'm new to this, and have no idea how to json_encode data. Would I have to encode all the data (both parent and child rows) or could I just encode the child data - reason being the parent row contains several ticked and unticked checkboxes (that's one of the reasons for the processing at the start of the while loop). The child row is read only and could contain the data as lines of text.

Comment: Yeah, I'd say just encode it all. You can read all the rows from your query into an array, like `while($row = $query->fetch_array()) $rows[] = $row;` and then `echo json_encode(['data' => $rows]);` will give you a JSON object like the one shown in the Ajax tab in that example. You can read that into the DataTable using [`data`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/data) instead of `ajax` like they're doing.

Comment: Sorry for putting code in the comments. I know it's hard to read like that, but I don't think I have enough to make a complete answer, just a suggestion at this point.

Comment: Have spent a lot of the night trying to work out how to do this. I am having trouble with checkboxes (basically one of the database columns is a fixed-length string consisting of 8 0s and 1s and these are used to check, or not, checkboxes in the table - this is what the original processing does). I don't think I can handle this easily using JSON as used in the examples.

Comment: OK - sorted. Stopped trying to use Datatables, and just used Bootstrap,  simple JQuery  and CSS to sort it out. There is a query about saving data, but that is for another question if I can't sort it out.